# Buildroot date is set to Jan 1, 1970

Tags: date, buildroot

why does buildroot automatically set the date in the title. And how do I fix that? Or do I have to make a script to manually set that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet connection, your ntp client will update the date and time automatically. Otherwise you have to use a RTC and get date and time on boot with "hwclock-w"